# React Native Complex Shadow With Inset's

Tags: css, react-native, shadow

I have a very (relatively) complex style requirement for a component. Part of the complexity comes from the CSS `box-shadow` property. As we know, React Native does not offer this property. Instead, one has to make use of the four style properties `shadowOffset`, `shadowRadius`, `shadowColor` and `shadowOpacity`. For this component, I have four actual shadows, two of which have `inset` -- which, React Native does not support insets.

Here's the CSS snippet I'm aiming to implement:

```css
background: #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 0px 16px 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07), 
       0px 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07), 
       inset 0px 2px 4px #FFFFFF, 
       inset 0px -2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-radius: 16px;
```

I'm at a total loss. I've tried more than a few things. I've tried using the out-of-the-box `shadow*` properties with React Native, and trying to recreate an inset like [this fella](https://github.com/rohailaltaf/react-native-inset-shadow) did. I've tried using [styled components](https://styled-components.com/docs). I even tried to hack together using SVG (this requirement is coming from Figma which offers an SVG).

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

I'm thinking maybe my only option is to bridge to a native iOS component, but I've never bridged that gap and it seems intimidating.

Comment: did you find any sol?

Answer (score -1):

```
 <LinearGradient
  style={styles.gradientButton}
  colors={['#040406', '#040406', '#040406', '#444446']}
  start={{ x: 0.48, y: 0.1 }}
  end={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.6 }}
>
```

with background #777 works good

[image: see image]